# How to connect to SignalR Hub continuously using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, signalr

I need to check availability of SignalR HUB from Web App. I need to try to connect from ASP .NET WebApp to SignalR HUB within interval until server become online.

I am using this javascript.

```
interval = setInterval(checkifconnected, 3000);

function checkifconnected() {

if ($.connection.hub && $.connection.hub.state === 
$.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {                        
$.connection.hub.start();

if ($.connection.hub && $.connection.hub.state === 
$.signalR.connectionState.connected) {                        
clearInterval(interval);
}
};
```

The problem is if hub is started once and server is not online the App is not reconnecting to it. How to solve it?

Comment: this might help http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#continuousreconnect

Comment: I checked it. I am using `$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
setTimeout(function() {...});` But, If I connect once - everything is ok. But how to reconnect to server if server just offline, within some time? How to wait for server? For example - every 5 sec to check is it available or not?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
if ($.connection.hub && $.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.reconnected) {window.location.reload()};
```

After first run of

```
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Connection state is

```
$.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.reconnected
```

I just refresh a window using

```
window.location.reload()
```

So, if SignalR hub is offline the page refresh is occurs after fixed interval and the client is trying to connect again.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reloading the page you can just call the start method when the hub is disconnected.

```
  $.connection.hub.disconnected(function (error) {
    console.log('Disconnection error :' + error)
    $.connection.hub.start(function (connection) {
      console.log("reconnected:" + connection)
    });
  });
```